# The alt text of an image shown should stay visible for at least 7 seconds on each rollover

Tags: javascript

I need to display the alt/title text of an image stay visible for at least 7 seconds on each rollover.

Comment: This is a browser setting, and not having to do with JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery "clueTip" plugin ( http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/#options ) supports a timed expiration (i.e., the little text box closes), though the docs mark it as "experimental."

Answer (score 0):

alt text is supposed to either always be visible, if images are not supported or are turned off in the browser, or never be visible, if the image is present. Some browsers show the alt text as if it was a title, but if a title is present as well as the required alt text, the title will be shown and not the alt text.

You may prefer a tooltip with a timed display if you need to enforce the visibility duration, most systems lose the title in less than 7 seconds.